# How to assure a range for a specific variable in Pyomo

Tags: python, constraint, pyomo

I would like to specify a certain range for a variable for a certain timeslot in Pyomo. I have a temperature variable $T(t)$ that is defined by using the difference equation $$T(t) = T(t-1) + \cdots,\quad\forall t>1.$$ But for the last value of the timeslot `t_end` the temperature should be between two limits `T_init + 0.1 >= T(t_end) >= T_init - 0.1`, where `T_init` is a constant temperature value at the beginning of the optimization. How can I realize that in Pyomo? I have only set one boundary so far (either the greater than or equal or the less than or equal constraint). Here is the code that I have:

```
def temperatureBufferStorageConstraintRule(model, t):
    if t == model.set_timeslots.first():
        return model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[t] == SetUpScenarios.initialBufferStorageTemperature
    if t == model.set_timeslots.last():
         return  SetUpScenarios.initialBufferStorageTemperature + 0.1 >=  model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[t] >= SetUpScenarios.initialBufferStorageTemperature - 0.1
    return model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[t] == model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[t-1] + ((model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating[t] * model.param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating[t] *  SetUpScenarios.electricalPower_HP * SetUpScenarios.timeResolution - model.param_heatDemand_In_W [t]  * SetUpScenarios.timeResolution - SetUpScenarios.standingLossesBufferStorage * SetUpScenarios.timeResolution) / (SetUpScenarios.capacityOfBufferStorage * SetUpScenarios.densityOfCement * SetUpScenarios.specificHeatCapacityOfCement))



model.constraint_temperatureBufferStorage = pyo.Constraint (model.set_timeslots, rule=temperatureBufferStorageConstraintRule)

model.constraint_temperatureBufferStorage.pprint()
```

You do not have to care about the exact definition of `model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[t]` which is the $T(t)$. Basically only the line with `if t == model.set_timeslots.last():` is important. Just for clarification I want to mention that I load all the constant values from a class called `SetUpScenarios` but this is not so important I guess for my question.
When using my code I only realize the less than or equal constraint and get the following output when printing the constraint:

```
variable_temperatureBufferStorage[288] :  21.1 :   True
```

Do you know how I can combine those two constraints and also realize the less than or equal constraint? I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way, I only change second if clause in def:

```
if t == model.set_timeslots.last():
        return  SetUpScenarios.initialBufferStorageTemperature + 0.1 >=  model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[t]
```

And second part of combined constraint is added separetly:

```
model.constraint_temperatureBufferStorage_last = Constraint(expr = model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage[model.set_timeslots.last()*] >= SetUpScenarios.initialBufferStorageTemperature - 0.1
```

- : I don't know data type of model.set_timeslots.last(), therefore I used as.

Comment: Thanks kur ag for your answer. It helped a lot. I accepted and upvoted your answer